# how to solve undefined reference on fortran codeblocks?

Tags: fortran, codeblocks, gfortran, mingw32

I am trying to use fortran 90 and so i installed code blocks ide and i downloaded mingw compiler too and all library related to them .[i did compiler setting as shown but unfortunately some errors occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hgop.jpg)

please help me how to fix it

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please copy and paste the error into the question *as text*. Use the [edit] feature. Please not that we have several questions and answers about the same error in various contexts. Please read them. Also, use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: We will also need to know the steps you used to install the compiler and the name of your source file.